# Exiting Loop with ACID Transactions with Knex SQL Query Builder & Bluebird in Node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, acid, knex.js

We're using the Knex SQL Query Builder to perform ACID transaction in Node and are we're experiencing some strange behavior while using a loop with Knex. The code below takes an array of tables and then conditionally performs an insert or update. The first table is 'transactionHeader' and is processed first. Then, the rows in the 'transactionDetail' table are processed within the overall transaction. New keys (rowids) are accumulated in the 'rowids' array.

**PROBLEM**: The main problem is that it seems to be impossible to exit the loop in processTransactionDetail() if there's an error returned from Knex. Neither throw nor return will exit the loop or the function. This means that if there is an error processing the transactionDetail it will continue to process the remaining rows before exiting.

```
    let rowids: any[] = [];

    knex.transaction(function(trx) {

        // Process transactionHeader
        if (transactionHeader.rowid) {

            // Update transactionHeader
            trx('transaction')
                .transacting(trx)
                .update(transactionHeader)
                .where('rowid', transactionHeader.rowid)
                .then(function(transactionrowid) {
                    rowids.push({ table: 'transaction', rowid: transactionHeader.rowid });
                    // Update transactionDetail rows.
                    processTransactionDetail(transactionrowid, trx);
                })
                .catch(trx.rollback);

        } else {

            // Insert transactionHeader
            trx('transaction')
                .transacting(trx)
                .insert(transactionHeader, 'rowid')
                .then(function(transactionrowid) {
                    rowids.push({ table: 'transaction', rowid: transactionrowid });
                    // Insert transactionDetail rows.
                    processTransactionDetail(transactionrowid, trx);
                })
                .catch(trx.rollback);
        }

    }).then(function(inserts) {
        console.log('success!', rowids)
        callback(null, { success: true }, { data: rowids })
        return;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('error', error);
        callback(null, {
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        }, { data: rowids })
        return;
    });

    /*
    * Process transactionDetail rows.
    */
    function processTransactionDetail(transactionHeaderRowID: number, trx) {

        var promise: any;
        let table: TABLE;
        let rowid: number;

        for (let i = 1; i < tablesToProcess.length; i++) {

            table = tablesToProcess[i];
            rowid = table.data[0].rowid;

            // Update
            if (rowid) {

                for (let row = 0; row < table.data.length; row++) {

                    promise = knex(table.name)
                        .transacting(trx)
                        .update(table.data[row])
                        .where('rowid', rowid)
                        .then(function(rowid) {                                
                            rowids.push({ table: table.name, rowid: rowid });
                        .catch(function(error) {                                
                             // --------------------------------
                             // **PROBLEM**: THERE IS NO WAY TO BREAK FROM THE LOOP
                             // --------------------------------
                             throw 'error';
                             return;
                             // --------------------------------
                        })
                 } 

            // Insert
            } else {

                for (let row = 0; row < table.data.length; row++) {

                    promise = knex(table.name)
                        .transacting(trx)
                        .insert(table.data[row])
                        .then(function(rowid) {
                            rowids.push({ table: table.name, rowid: rowid });
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                             // --------------------------------
                             // **PROBLEM**: THERE IS NO WAY TO BREAK FROM THE LOOP
                             // --------------------------------
                             throw 'error';
                             return;
                             // --------------------------------
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        promise.then(function(x) {
            promise.then(trx.commit);
        });
    }
```

**UPDATED:** Is this a proper structure? Not sure the error handlers at the bottom are really needed.

```
    knex.transaction(function(trx) {

        // Update Row
        function updateRow(table, rowid, row) {
            return knex(table.name)
                .transacting(trx)
                .update(row)
                .where('rowid', rowid)
                .then(function(rowid) {

                    rowids.push({
                        table: table.name,
                        rowid: rowid
                    });
                });
        }

        // Insert Row
        function insertRow(table, rowid, row) {
            return knex(table.name)
                .transacting(trx)
                .insert(row)
                .then(function(rowid) {

                    rowids.push({
                        table: table.name,
                        rowid: rowid
                    });
                });
        }

        // Process Tables
        Promise.mapSeries(tablesToProcess, function(table) {

            let rowid = table.data[0].rowid;

            // choose the right function to apply to the rows
            var fn = rowid ? updateRow : insertRow;

            // fn needs table and rowid
            fn = fn.bind(this, table, rowid);

            // Process Rows
            return Promise.mapSeries(table.data, fn)
                .then(function(result) {

                    // result is an array with all the knex promises result
                    return result;

                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log('an error happened');
                    //trx.rollback();  // QUESTION: IS THIS NEEDED?
                    throw err;     // IS THERE A WAY TO
                });

        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log('success', result);
            trx.commit();
            // callback(null, { success: true }, { data: rowids })
            // return;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('error', error);
            trx.rollback();
            callback(null, { success: false, message: error.message }, { data: rowids })
        });

    }).then(function(inserts) {
        console.log('success!', rowids)
        callback(null, { success: true }, { data: rowids })
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error', error);
        callback(null, { success: false, message: error.message }, { data: rowids })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with promises so you have to use a way to loop supporting them. There is [bluebird's `mapSeries()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) for example:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function updateRow(table, rowid, row) {
  return knex(table.name)
    .transacting(trx)
    .update(table.data[row])
    .where('rowid', rowid)
    .then(function(rowid) {
      rowids.push({
        table: table.name,
        rowid: rowid
      });
    });
}

function insertRow(table, rowid, row) {
  return knex(table.name)
    .transacting(trx)
    .insert(table.data[row])
    .then(function(rowid) {
      rowids.push({
        table: table.name,
        rowid: rowid
      });
    });
}

// if there is an error, the iteration will stop immediately
Promise.mapSeries(tablesToProcess, function(table) {
  rowid = table.data[0].rowid;

  // choose the right function to apply to the rows
  var fn = rowid ? updateRow : insertRow;
  // fn need table and rowid
  fn = fn.bind(this, table, rowid);

  // call fn for each row
  // if there is an error, the iteration will stop immediately
  return Promise.mapSeries(table.data, fn)
    .then(function(result) {
      // result is an array with all the knex promises result
      return result;
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('an error happened');
      trx.rollback();
      throw err;
    });
}).then(function(result) {
  console.log('all is good');
  // you can safely commit here
  trx.commit();
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('an error happened');
  trx.rollback();
});
```

**Update**

About your questions:

```
knex.transaction(function (trx) {
    // Update Row
    function updateRow(table, rowid, row) {
        return knex(table.name)
            .transacting(trx)
            .update(row)
            .where('rowid', rowid)
            .then(function (rowid) {
                rowids.push({
                    table: table.name,
                    rowid: rowid
                });
            });
    }

    // Insert Row
    function insertRow(table, rowid, row) {
        return knex(table.name)
            .transacting(trx)
            .insert(row)
            .then(function (rowid) {
                rowids.push({
                    table: table.name,
                    rowid: rowid
                });
            });
    }

    // you need to return here so the 'then(function (inserts)' and the catch work
    // Process Tables
    return Promise.mapSeries(tablesToProcess, function (table) {
        let rowid = table.data[0].rowid;

        // choose the right function to apply to the rows
        var fn = rowid ? updateRow : insertRow;

        // fn needs table and rowid
        fn = fn.bind(this, table, rowid);

        // Process Rows
        // if you don't do anything special in the then and the catch, you can remove them
        return Promise.mapSeries(table.data, fn)
            .then(function (result) {
                // result is an array with all the knex promises result
                return result;
            }).catch(function (err) {
                // this catch is not necessary,
                // you can remove it you don't need to do something here
                console.log('an error happened');
                //trx.rollback();  // QUESTION: IS THIS NEEDED? << // no, my mistake, the rollback is done on the other catch
                throw err;     // IS THERE A WAY TO
            });
    }).then(function (result) {
        console.log('success', result);
        trx.commit();
        return result;
        // callback(null, { success: true }, { data: rowids })
        // return;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
        trx.rollback();
        throw error; // always rethrow error when you chain, if you don't, it's like the promise is resolved (ok) 
        // you already do this below
        // callback(null, { success: false, message: error.message }, { data: rowids });
    });
}).then(function (inserts) {
    console.log('success!', rowids)
    callback(null, { success: true }, { data: rowids })
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
    callback(null, { success: false, message: error.message }, { data: rowids })
});
```

The 2 then and 2 catch at the bottom could be merged. Also, why is there a callback? It's better to not mix Promises and callbacks unless you can't avoid it.

Comment: This was very helpful! I've updated the example above with some questions.

Comment: One problem I'm having is that this endpoint works fine the first time, but cannot be called after that. Not sure if has anything to do with Bluebird or not.

Comment: @ASA2 About the hanging, I think it was because you're missing few returns in the code so some Promises are just running and not "waited". There is a good article about promises: http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html It's very useful to avoid common mistakes.